# sqlalchemy/sqlmodel: return total count of all rows from multiple table joins?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm joining multiple tables and returning all the columns fine. I want to now return the total count of all rows

```
select(Transaction.id, func.count(Transaction.id)).label('count_1'))
        .join(TransactionType).join(xxx).group_by(Transaction.id)
```

which returns an SQL like:

```
SELECT transaction.id, count(transaction.id) AS count_1 
FROM transaction INNER JOIN xxx ON xxx.`xId` = transaction.`xId` INNER JOIN 
transaction_type ON transaction_type.id = transaction.`transaction_type` GROUP BY transaction.id
```

However, what this does is just return `count_1` as `1` for every single row. I was expecting it to return count of all the rows. If I don't use `group_by` then it will complain but I suspect this is why this is happening.

How can I get the total row count in SQLalchemy/SQLmodel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up just grabbing the length of `len(session.exec(sql).all())`

Comment: I think that answering your own question would be more effective if you were able to include the entire solution or answer to the question you posted, instead of just a small snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of typo in parenthesis closing. The label should be for the func.count as follows.

```py
select(Transaction.id, func.count(Transaction.id).label('count_1')) # look where .label is applied.
    .join(TransactionType).join(xxx).group_by(Transaction.id)
```

Comment: i mistyped the real code contains the proper closing

Comment: If you just join two tables (Transaction and TransactionType), does the code work as expected?

Comment: no diffference there

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.
I was using asynchronous requests.

The below solution worked for me in SQLModel:

```
# Import func tool 
from sqlmodel import select, func

#sqlmodel query
statement = select(func.count(Model_1.id)).where(
        Model_1.column_1 == Model_2.matching_column,
        Model_1.column_2 == "some_value_1" ,
        Model_2.column_2 == "some_value_2",
    )
#execute query (asynchronous request)
result_object = await session.exec(statement)
count = result_object.one() # this will return the value eg: 100
count = result_object.all() # this will return result as a list eg: [100]
```

Hope this helps.!